# Change font and font size during creating userform programatically

Tags: excel, vba

I am going to create a userform programmatically, I am able to create other controls like commandbuttons, textboxes, optionbuttons...etc., as my wish.

But I can not figure out the way to set the font and font size at the beginning of creating the userform programmatically.

As there are near hundred controls, it would be better for me to set the font at the beginning, otherwise, I may set the font manually afterwards.

I tried the following for setting:

```
    Dim NewForm As Object

    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True

    Set NewForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
    With NewForm
        .Properties("Caption") = ""
        .Properties("Width") = 400
        .Properties("Height") = 400
------> 'Properties("Font.Name") = "Arial"
        'Properties("Font.size") = 9
               'Or
------> '.Font = "Arial"
        '.font.size = 9
        .Name = "frmWebScraping"
    End With

    'code for creating other controls with no problem is neglected

End Sub
```

Comment: But the caption, width, height are also properties, they also work. So is there a way to set the font properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct properties are:

```
.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Name") = "Arial"
.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Size") = 9
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Peh. You teach me the correct grammar under this requirement. Honestly, I go through days for the lines. But not much was mentioned even on office dev  center. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TingFungLi You can use the *Local* window in the VBE to investigate what properties exist in `NewForm.Properties`. See my screenshot. This way you can find out without having any documentation.